# sending fake event to GTKEntry

Tags: keyevent, key-events, gtkentry

I'm using gtk-3.0 to create my simple UI and I want to send a fake event to GTKEntry via *g_signal_emit(...)* function.
Actually, I don't know, what parameters I should pass to this function.

Comment: You need to provide a bit more detail in your question - the answer to the question depends on which signal you are trying to emit.

Answer (score 1):

Source: https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtkmm-list/2007-June/msg00115.html

```
void Foo:bar() // handler for signal_clicked()
{
        <YOUR TREEVIEW>.grab_focus(); // essential

        guint keyval = GDK_Page_Down;

        GdkKeymapKey* keys;
        gint n_keys;
        gdk_keymap_get_entries_for_keyval(gdk_keymap_get_default(),
                                          keyval,
                                          &keys,
                                          &n_keys);
    // Note: GdkEvent is an union
        GdkEvent* event = gdk_event_new(GDK_KEY_PRESS);
        ((GdkEventKey*)event)->window =
                             <YOUR TREEVIEW>get_window()->gobj();
        ((GdkEventKey*)event)->send_event = TRUE;
        ((GdkEventKey*)event)->time = GDK_CURRENT_TIME;
        ((GdkEventKey*)event)->state = GDK_KEY_PRESS_MASK;
        ((GdkEventKey*)event)->keyval = keyval;
        ((GdkEventKey*)event)->hardware_keycode = keys[0].keycode;
        ((GdkEventKey*)event)->group = keys[0].group;

        gdk_event_put(event);
//      Or, more gdkmm-ish:
//      Gdk::Event(event).put();
}
```